# WinApi - create file invalid_handle_value

Tags: c++, winapi

Hi I have code as below:

```
LPSTR Bufor;
DWORD dwRozmiar, dwPrzeczyt;
HANDLE hPlik;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT msg,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

hPlik = CreateFile( "test.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL );
if( hPlik == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
    MessageBox( NULL, "Cant open a file", "Error1!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );
    PostQuitMessage( 0 );
}



Bufor[ dwRozmiar ] = 0;
SetWindowText( hwnd, Bufor ); 

}
```

And I get invalid_handle_value? Why?
Program shows first messagebox that: Can't open a file.

When I call `GetLastError`, the value 32 is returned.

Comment: *If the function fails, the return value is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.* ***To get extended error information, call GetLastError.***

Comment: Try giving the file name a fully qualified path, as the flags you have set for the call will fail if the file is not found.

Comment: Especially if you're running this from inside the IDE, chances are that the problem stems from the current directory not being what you expect. Since you haven't specified a path to the file, it needs to be in the process' current directory to open successfully.

Comment: Error 32, even after put a path to file

Comment: That information should have been put in the question. I did that for you. Error codes are all described on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows error code 32 is [`ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx). Which means that the file has already been opened by by some other entity using a sharing mode that denies your process access.

That other entity appears to be your own program. You open the file and then fail to close it.

Your window proc is completely broken too. It's time to step back a little and master the basics.

Comment: Apparently it is. How to solve it? Find out which other entity has it open. It's most likely your own program. Have I answered your question now?

Comment: I moved this file to another PC and I get same error after first open. If I put FILE_SHARE_READ program stop working:/

Comment: You probably failed to close the file. Surely I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: At the end I have: 
GlobalFree( Bufor );
CloseHandle( hPlik );

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site where you ask a specific question. I answered that. It is not a place where someone debugs your program for you. I have already told you what's wrong.